# How to properly refactor router components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, dry

I'm building a to-do list app in React. With React-Router it has routes for "/all", "/today", "/week", "/inbox", and custom "/:projectId" tasks. They all render the same component `<TaskList />` which accepts a couple of props:

- Project ID, to add tasks to
- Project Name, and
- Tasks belonging to the respective project

I don't know how to properly refactor such code so that it's as efficient and DRY as possible. Here's my current attempt:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  selectAllTasks,
  selectTodayTasks,
  selectWeekTasks,
  selectProjectTasks
} from "../../redux/tasks.module";

import { selectCurrentProject } from "../../redux/projects.module";

import TaskList from "../task-list/task-list.component";

const projectId = 0; // Tasks entered will be added to Inbox

export const AllTasks = () => {
  const tasks = useSelector(selectAllTasks);

  return <TaskList projectName="All" projectId={projectId} tasks={tasks} />;
};

export const TodayTasks = () => {
  const tasks = useSelector(selectTodayTasks);

  return <TaskList projectName="Today" projectId={projectId} tasks={tasks} />;
};

export const WeekTasks = () => {
  const tasks = useSelector(selectWeekTasks);

  return (
    <TaskList projectName="Next 7 Days" projectId={projectId} tasks={tasks} />
  );
};

export const ProjectTasks = () => {
  const { projectId } = useParams();
  const { text } = useSelector(state => selectCurrentProject(state, projectId));
  const tasks = useSelector(state => selectProjectTasks(state, projectId));

  return <TaskList projectName={text} projectId={projectId} tasks={tasks} />;
};
```

And here's the page that calls them:

```
import { Switch, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "../../components/header/header.component";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/sidebar.component";
import {
  AllTasks,
  TodayTasks,
  WeekTasks,
  ProjectTasks
} from "../../components/filters/filters.component";

import useStyles from "./tasks.styles";

const TasksPage = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Header />
      <Sidebar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/all`} component={AllTasks} />
        <Route exact path={`${path}/today`} component={TodayTasks} />
        <Route exact path={`${path}/week`} component={WeekTasks} />
        <Route exact path={`${path}/:projectId`} component={ProjectTasks} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TasksPage;
```

What's the most efficient way to structure this? And allow not only the hardcoded routes (i.e. all, today, week, etc.) but also the custom user project routes (/:projectId) to coexist and not have repeating code?
Thank you so much.